# Particle in a circle with infinite walls; can there be a singularity at the origin?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

Consider a particle inside a circle of radius $R$ such that the potential is zero everywhere inside the circle, but infinite potential at the walls. In that case, the Schrodinger equation is given by:
\begin{equation}
\frac{-\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2 \psi = E\psi
\end{equation}

We can expand $\nabla^2$ in polar coordinates, perform variable seperation between the radial and angular parts of the solution by writing $\psi(\textbf{r}) = R(r)\Theta(\theta)$ and substitute $r'=\sqrt{\frac{2mE}{\hbar^2}}r$ to get the following equation:

\begin{equation}
r'^2 \frac{\partial^2 R}{\partial r^2} + r' \frac{\partial R}{\partial r'} + R(r'^2-m^2) = 0
\end{equation}

This is the Bessel equation, and it can be solved by the Bessel functions of the first kind $J_n(x)$ or the Bessel functions of the second kind $Y_n(x)$.

Now, it seems like everyone (for example, here: https://galileo.phys.virginia.edu/classes/252/2d_wells.html) says that the wavefunction should be zero at $r=R$ AND that the wavefunction should be finite at the origin. They then use the first zero of the Bessel function of the first kind (which happens to be at 2.4048) to get the following solution of the ground state:

\begin{equation}
E = \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \left(\frac{2.4048}{R}\right)^2
\end{equation}

However, why should the wavefunction be non-singular at the origin? If we relax that requirement, the Bessel function of the second kind has a zero at ~1 (instead of 2.4048); so we get a ground state energy of $E \approx \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \left(\frac{1}{R}\right)^2$ instead, which is much lower.

The singularity at the origin when we use $Y_n(x)$ instead of $J_n(x)$ is integrable, so it isn't that the probability density at the origin is infinite.

So, why should we force the wavefunction to remain non-singular at the origin, when the singularity seems harmless?

Comment: It would have to be *square integratable* at the origin. Is it?

Comment: Is it not? I've put it into Wolfram alpha and it seems to integrate it fine https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%28Y_0%28x%29%29%5E2+from+0+to+1

Comment: You need to integrate over a surface element, not a line, the same way that you need to integrate over a volume element for $3D$ wells.

Comment: @Gert I've included a surface element as well, it still appears to be integrable. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+2*pi*x%28Y_0%28x%29%29%5E2+dx+from+0+to+1

Comment: That link is truncated. I'd love to see it though. Kindly fix it, your point is worth considering...

Comment: Because infinite wave functions can lead to infinite derivatives, which would yield infinite momentum/energy. Second it breaks continuity of the wave function at the origin.

Comment: @Triatticus you meant *Infinite* wave functions, right?

Comment: @Gert yeah, typing on a mobile device can sometimes have strange effects.

Comment: @Triatticus Okay. What's the quantum momentum operator in this case?

Comment: The radial momentum operator is $-i\hbar\frac1r \frac{\partial}{\partial r} (r f(r))$. If you find the expectation value for the Bessel functions of the second kind it doesn't converge.

Comment: @Triatticus Thanks a lot. The momentum definitely goes to $\infty$ for $\lim_{r \to 0}$.